# Enumerating all paths with in a DAG from a source node, visiting only once

Tags: python, networkx, graph-algorithm

My goal is to create a lookup table by node, with each entry containing a list of successors to that particular node. E.g. if you have a graph

- A->B->C
- A->D->E->F
- A->D->E->G
- A->D->H

then the traversal order from A would be A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H. This is for a reactive programming mechanism, so my goal is if A is "activated" then I should visit all its successors depth-first. I also want to short-circuit, so if for instance "E" indicates it's a terminal node, the execution order would be A,B,C,D,E,H. I am currently using the networkx package in Python which offers BFS, DFS, topological sorting and a great number of other algorithms, but I haven't found a way to do what I'm trying to achieve with the built-in algorithms.

As an example that works (in terms of executing in the correct order):

```
def activate(self, evt: Event):
    nodes = networkx.descendants(self.graph, evt)
    ordering = networkx.topological_sort(networkx.subgraph(self.graph, nodes))
    for node in ordering:
        node.on_activate()
```

but this is missing a key feature: the ability to short-circuit and stop the event propagation if on_activate() returns false. With a bit of hacking I found the following works, but I am not sure if it's the optimal or most elegant solution. Essentially I take the topological sort and scan forward to find the next non-terminal node to suppress propagation:

```
# noinspection PyCallingNonCallable
def activate(self, evt: Event):
    nodes = networkx.descendants(self.graph, evt)
    ordering = networkx.topological_sort(networkx.subgraph(self.graph, nodes))
    self.__clear_activation_flags()

    # process the originating node
    if not evt.on_activate():
        return
    else:
        self.activation_flags[evt] = True

    # process the node's descendents
    for node in ordering:
        if not node.on_activate():
            # skip forward to the next terminal node
            skipping = True
            while skipping:
                node = next(ordering, None)
                if not node or self.graph.out_degree(node) == 0:
                    skipping = False
        else:
            self.activation_flags[node] = True
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us what your code looks like?

Comment: Hi rassar, I have updated the original question with a small block of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DFS should solve this problem

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'D'],
        'B' : ['C'],
        'C':  ['P'],
        'D': ['E', 'H'],
        'E': ['F', 'G'],
        'F': [],
        'G': [],
        'H': [],
        'P': ['D', 'Q'],
        'Q' : []}
terminal_nodes = ['C']     
path=[]

def _dfs_visit(start_node):
    if start_node in path or start_node in terminal_nodes:
        return
    path.append(start_node)
    for node in graph[start_node]:
        print (path)
        _dfs_visit(node)

_dfs_visit('A', )
print (path)
```